# Guidelines for Facebook SDK login in Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I would like some pointers about how to integrate Facebook login into my app and backend. I would like to use the credentials that Facebook gives me (as the user authenticates) to sign all the requests that the app does to my back-end.

But then token might expire? I am not sure what would be the correct workflow. How should I link the Facebook identity of someone to his identity in my own app?

Comment: try this link http://sunil-android.blogspot.in/2013/08/facebook-integration-with-android-app.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the correct link, here's the [official tokens docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/).